# TCP connection is Possible by Using different IP , but same port?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, redhat

In Linux machine.

Using a different IP , but same port binding

```
(Client_IP:A, Port:B, Server_IP:C, Port:D) ==> TCP connection is established
              :
              : 'usable port is exahusted' 
              :
(Clinet_IP:E, Port:B, Server_IP:C, Port:D) ==> TCP Port binding error...
```

If I reuse port B, Linux kernel occurred tcp port binding error because port already in use ?

Answer (score 1):

A connection endpoint is uniquely identified by its address *and* port (and protocol type). So if you have another address you can use the same port, as it's not the same endpoint as the first.

Comment: Actually the uniqueness is in the combination of source and destination addresses and ports.  So for example multiple clients can connect to the same http server on port 80, but the connections are unique because the client's addresses and/or source ports are different.